# Intellij WebStorm/PHPStorm autocomplete and type check using jQuery-DefinitelyTyped, what is the best way

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, phpstorm, webstorm

i want to have a proper autocomplete and type check for jQuery and light code at the same time.
question: what are the best practices, how to combine it by jetbrains products?
in settings->js libraries i have enabled only standard html and `jquery-DefinitelyTyped`
here some start code example:

```
//simple on ready construct, assume $ is already used by another framework
jQuery(function($){
    //alias for global
    var j = jQuery; //should i use `var $ = jQuery` everytime in such construct?

    //force type
    /** @type {JQueryStatic} */
    var jq = $;

    //ctrl+q -> fast info results:
    var temp1 = $('.selector'); //bad temp1 type : *|jQuery|HTMLElement
    var temp2 = jq('.selector');//error "Method expression is not of Function type
    var temp3 = j('.selector'); //ok temp3 type: JQuery
    $(window).scrollTop(30);    //error scrollTop is not a function
    jq(window).scrollTop(30);   //error "Method expression is not of Function type
    j(window).scrollTop(30);    //ok
});
```